# oozie workflow should only run if there is an input hdfs file available

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I set up coordinator `<dataset>` and `<input-events>` values and timeout.
A coordinator is working fine as it'll check if an input file is available at a hdfs location only then it's running the workflow else timed out.
I need the same behavior in the workflow like if I am running only a workflow without coordinator then workflow should behave same as of above-mentioned coordinator's behavior.
I tried `mapred.input.dir` but workflow ran successfully.
Is there any another way we could achieve the same.
Workflow is a simple hello world job not a map-reduce job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrokflow is for running jobs on-demand. **The functionality you are looking for is not available in Workflow**. That functionality is provided by the Coordinator.

Comment: it worked using <file> param in java action. WF java action failed stating file is missing but I still need to figure out timed out part or there is no waiting for <file> dependency in WF.